# Index of last element in array VBA using Application.Match

Tags: arrays, vba

Consider the following piece of VBA code, which generates an array with only two elements, searching for the latter of the two elements. The two commented lines will add a third entry to the array. This produces the output

> Error 2042

in the Immediate window. If I change the script to a three element array, and try to `Match` the second element, I get the proper index in return. If I, however, search for the last element, I get the same error.

Why is this happening?

Working MWE

```
Sub testArray()
Dim myArray() As Variant
' ReDim myArray(1 To 2)
ReDim myArray(1 To 3)
myArray(1) = "Trondheim"
myArray(2) = "Levanger"
myArray(3) = "Dummy"

Dim Index As Variant
Dim test As Variant

test = "Levanger"
Index = Application.Match(test, myArray)
Debug.Print Index
End Sub
```

Minimal non-working example

```
Sub testArray()
Dim myArray() As Variant
' ReDim myArray(1 To 2)
ReDim myArray(1 To 3)
myArray(1) = "Trondheim"
myArray(2) = "Levanger"
myArray(3) = "Dummy"

Dim Index As Variant
Dim test As Variant

'test = "Levanger"
test = "Dummy"
Index = Application.Match(test, myArray)
Debug.Print Index
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this in Access? I cant get the code to work in Excel (no `Application.Match`)

Comment: For extra clarity, could you paste up the code in the not-working state?

Comment: This is in the VBA environment in Excel 2010.

Comment: I think that `match` is expecting a 2-D array (which is how ranges are represented) and doesn't know how to handle a pointer to a 1-D array. The underlying C/C++ code must be trying to treat it as a 2-D array (just a guess).

Comment: Would you not need to loop through the array to check for a match?

Comment: @JohnColeman you can use a single dimension array with `Match` - for example `Application.Match(3, Array(2, 3, 4), 0)` will work

Comment: @MacroMan Well -- it seems my guess was false! I had never used `Match` on anything other than a range.

Comment: @JohnColeman your theory is correct - when used as a worksheet function there must be some conversion as a column would return a 2-D array. But unfortunately as there is no view-able source code we will never know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give 0 as optional parameter `match_type`:

```
Index = Application.Match(test, myArray, 0)
```

It causes that the function will return the exact match.

According to the Excel help, if this parameter is omitted, by default `match_type = 1` is used.

In that case
"MATCH finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value. The values in the lookup_array argument must be placed in ascending order, for example: ...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE, TRUE."

Comment: Could you please elaborate why this solves the problem, and why it occures? Is @John Coleman right?

Comment: @Holene No, he's not right, since as you said, the function works properly for second item if there are three items in your array - that means it accepts 1D arrays. I edited my answer to explain it. If you try the same function in Excel worksheet it will give you the same error for third item.

Comment: @Holene - For both [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) and [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) the data must be sorted if anything but **0** or FALSE is specified. For MATCH this could be ascending or descending depending upon whether **-1** or **1** is specified for the *range_lookup* parameter.

Comment: Note that since `Application.Match` *can* return an error type, OP may want to do some error-handling in case the match isn't found.  But otherwise, good answer + explanation!!

Comment: @Jeeped So if I understand you guys correctly, it's a little random that my code doesn't work properly? Using `myArray=[6, 7, 8]` and searching for 8 works as the array now is populated by strictly increasing values. Thanks!

Comment: @Holene - Strictly speaking, if the values were in ascending order then it should work reliably without the **0** parameter. However, since that was not intentional there is no guarantee that the ascending order would be maintained so any correct result can only be considered coincidental.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify an exact match type, as the strings are not compared as actual text:

---

***Example 1: No argument supplied***

```
Sub MM()

Dim myArray As Variant

myArray = Array("test", "best", "rest")

Index = Application.Match("test", myArray)
Debug.Print Index    '// Prints "3"

Index = Application.Match("rest", myArray)
Debug.Print Index    '// Also prints "3"

End Sub
```

The default match type argument is **1** - *Less Than* which appears to implicilty evalute each item on it's code value rather than it's text value - even when `Option Compare` statements are used. For this reason it is always advised to use these type of function with data that has already been sorted.

This *kind of* makes sense as there has to be a numerical value derived at *some* level in order for a 'less than' comparison to occur.

---

***Example 2: Match Argument Supplied***

```
Sub MM()

Dim myArray As Variant

myArray = Array("test", "best", "rest")

Index = Application.Match("test", myArray, 0)
Debug.Print Index    '// Prints "1"

Index = Application.Match("rest", myArray, 0)
Debug.Print Index    '// Prints "3"

End Sub
```

As you can see - this gives the *expected* output. We have supplied the match argument **0** - *Exact Match* which when supplied with a **valid** lookup value will return the correct index whether comparing on a binary *or* text basis because the values are identical.